# unable to start embedded tomcat server

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, gradle

I use eclipse spring boot ide.
and it works fine inside eclipse.
but, build when I run jar, I get an error.
The error details are as follows.

```
Application run failed
org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
```

my build.Gradle dependencies config as follows.

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.6'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.2.4.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the reference docs about creating executable jars/wars with Spring Boot + Gradle? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.M1/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable

Comment: Try with changing the port number.

Comment: can you show me your application.properties / yml

Comment: Remove the `version` from the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency. Make sure you aren't mixing jars/modules from different versions. Make sure you applied the Spring Boot plugin to create the jar.